# Send field from table in php generated from sql to another php form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to send the field id from my php main form to another page where I can display the full data from that user. By far I am generating the table like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>Form</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $row["name"] . ' ' . $row["surname"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["date"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td><p class='message'><a href='form.php'>Show form</a></p></td>";              
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    }
    else {
        echo "No data found";
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

I dont know how to retrieve the ID field for each row into the column Show form, so when I press it it opens the whole new form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not one name for the index / ID for all tables.  You need to look up the table design in the database, for example by using phpMyAdmin.

If the name is "userid" (it is probably something else!) then your code might look like this:

```
 <a href='form.php?id=" . $row["userid"] . "'>Show form</a></p></td>";
```

Also, form.php MUST NOT trust that id is safe!  Google "sql injection" and "Little Bobby Tables"

Comment: Oh didnt thought of that, thank you so much ^^ I will check those, as I need to prepare my code for Sql Injection too.